# vue document.getElementById style control failure

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

```
        <vs-tr :key="i" v-for="(daydatasT, i) in daydatas">
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.Machinecd }}</vs-td>
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.Checkdt }}</vs-td>
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.CheckItemnm }}</vs-td>
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.CheckPart }}</vs-td>
          <vs-td :id="[`d${i}`]">
          </vs-td>
          <vs-td></vs-td>
          <!-- <vs-td>{{ Checker }}</vs-td> -->
          <!-- <vs-td>{{ tr.CheckUser }}</vs-td> -->
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.Remark }}</vs-td>
        </vs-tr>
```

---

```
const vm = this;
    axios
      .post("~~~")
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log("response.data : " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
        vm.daydatas = response.data;
        // console.log(response.data[i].Checkresult);
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          if (response.data[i].Checkresult == "1") {
            document.getElementById(`d${i}`).style.background = "#e96666";
            document.getElementById(`d${i}`).style.color = "#ffffff";
          } else {
            document.getElementById(`d${i}`).style.background = "#ceecc5";
            document.getElementById(`d${i}`).style.color = "#176f24";
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

---

[image]

If I put a different ID, it works, but the style is not eaten for the ID increased by the for statement. I took a picture of the console to see if the names were different, but they are the same. why isn't it working?

Comment: dom is not ready you can solve the problem very simply by using vue's variable it is more recommended than using dom api

Comment: @TachibanaShin  :0!! What search terms can I use to get more information?

Comment: look for it with react keyword or you can follow the answer below i will write 1 code for you to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using vue 2 so this paragraph should solve your problem

```
   <vs-tr :key="i" v-for="(daydatasT, i) in daydatas">
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.Machinecd }}</vs-td>
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.Checkdt }}</vs-td>
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.CheckItemnm }}</vs-td>
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.CheckPart }}</vs-td>
          <!-- reactive -->
          <vs-td :style="stylesTd[i]">
          </vs-td>
          <vs-td></vs-td>
          <!-- <vs-td>{{ Checker }}</vs-td> -->
          <!-- <vs-td>{{ tr.CheckUser }}</vs-td> -->
          <vs-td>{{ daydatasT.Remark }}</vs-td>
        </vs-tr>
```

```
export default {
  ...
  data: {
    ...
    styles: []
  },
  methods: {
    ...
    <nameMethod>() {
      axios
      .post("~~~")
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log("response.data : " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
        this.daydatas = response.data;
        this.styles.splice(0)
        this.styles.push(
          // I think you want to iterate but if you only want the first 10 items you can also replace this with the for . function
          ...response.data.map(item => {
            if (item.Checkresult)
              return {
                background: "#e96666",
                color: "#ffffff"
              }
            return {
              background: "#ceecc5",
              color: "#176f24"
            }
          })
        )
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
  }
}
```